# Silverlight - Useful extension methods in system.data.* namespace

Tags: vb.net, silverlight, entity-framework, extension-methods

I have a number of very useful extension methods that I'd like to use in my Silverlight project.

I've pasted the Module here http://pastebin.com/TfBpNDWr

The problem I'm having is that visual studio complains that the dlls my module have been written against have not been built against the Silverlight runtime.

Is there an easy way to get these extension methods working in Silverlight?

I'm thinking my main hurdle is getting `IObjectSet` and `ObjectContext` to run against the Silverlight run-time - perhaps there's another way to expose these methods that I'm not aware of.

Comment: Possible dupe of [Same code base for WPF and Silverlight?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6968664/same-code-base-for-wpf-and-silverlight), [Share data types between silverlight and other applications](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1261216/share-data-types-between-silverlight-and-other-applications) and potentially many others.

Comment: Also check this from MSDN: [Chapter 10: Sharing Code Between Silverlight and WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921109%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx)

Comment: I can't find a way to do what I wanted to... but the more I think about it the more I consider that I shouldn't be.

I've created a DomainService that provides the extensions against the class's that I need it for in a case by case basis. It means a little more code needs to be written - but it means my data layer has better separation.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to reuse code in such way, there are these three options I'm aware of:

- Generally create all your basic class libraries as a Silverlight class library project, or, more officially, as a [Portable Class Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391.aspx). Throw all references out except for **mscorlib.dll**, **System.dll** and **System.Core.dll**. You can then link such kind of library in any full .NET project.
- You can link individual code files from another project with the "*Add as link*" feature (Right click project -> Add Existing Item -> Change "Add" Button to "Add as link"). That way you can create a Silverlight project and link individual files from your full .NET project. However that can get tedious if you have a lot of files and you often add/remove files and folders in your source project.
- To cure this problem, you may check out the Project Linker at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd458870.aspx ... but I haven't tried it myself yet.